# SignInManager class is throwing exception Invalid Object: "AspNetUserClaims

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Whenever I am calling any method of SignInManager class, its throwing mean exception.
Invalid Object name 'AspNetUserClaims'

I have not created AspNetUserClaims table while doing migration as I don't require AspNetUserClaims. I only need Users and Roles table.

I am using .Net 7 and Identity Service to provide Authentication and Authorization.

Please help me

I am expecting that my SignInManager class should work with AspNetUserClaims table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I found this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39387384) which looks like containing the same error with yours.

You mentioned that `Whenever I am calling any method of SignInManager class, its throwing mean exception`. So I checked the construction method of SignInManager and I found that it only has construction method like below which `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` is necessary.

[image]